# QT plugin loader doesn't instantiate a UI plugin

Tags: qt, user-interface, plugins

I've done a QT (4.6.3) program/GUI that loads plugins in real time and this works wonderfully.
Now I've just created a new plugin that differs from all the others because it has a .ui file as it should show a Dialog GUI when executed. Well, it cannot be instantiated by the plugin loader.

I've already tried to comment only the part with the ui stuff and in that case it's instantiated (but does, of course, nothing).

Is there something I'm missing ? is it possible that the ui code makes it incompatible with the other no GUI plugins ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my fault.

I forgot to include the .cpp file of the GUI in the CMakeList.txt :o
Strange I didn't get an error during compilation, but now it works.

Thanks anyway.